# Seperate data from an array from db to show in a different cell

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, frontend, antd

I tried to separate data from an array which has more than 2 values inside an array but there's an error.
Tried this method

```
 const columns = [
  {
            title: 'Project-Name',
            dataIndex: 'entrydata',
            key: 'project',
            render: (entrydata) =>
                entrydata.map((entry) => (
                    <div key={entry._id}>
                        <p>{entry.project}</p>
                    </div>
                )),
        },
  {
            title: 'Total Hours',
            dataIndex: 'entrydata',
            key: 'totalhours',
            render: (entrydata) =>
                entrydata.map((entry) => (
                    <div key={entry._id}>
                        <p>{entry.totalhours}</p>
                    </div>
                )),
        },  
    ];
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1xSg.png)
But the values shows in a same table.

The data from DB is as below:

```
{
        "_id": "645499c41666ee8236b1d826",
        "weekId": "16",
        "email": "sundar@forg.onmicrosoft.com",
        "userId": "EMP1234",
        "userName": "sundar C",
        "weekStartingDate": "17-04-2023",
        "weekEndingDate": "23-04-2023",
        "status": "Submitted",
        "reason": "",
        "reportingManager": "f admin",
        "weekTotal": "45",
        "entrydata": [
            {
                "TotalHours": 0,
                "project": "React",
                "task": "Leave",
                "day1": 0,
                "day2": 6,
                "day3": 3,
                "day4": 4,
                "day5": 1,
                "day6": 0,
                "day7": 0,
                "comments": "",
                "totalhours": 14,
                "_id": "64549a2d1666ee8236b1d832"
            },
            {
                "TotalHours": 0,
                "project": "EPM",
                "task": "logics",
                "day1": 3,
                "day2": 0,
                "day3": 4,
                "day4": 0,
                "day5": 0,
                "day6": 24,
                "day7": 0,
                "comments": "",
                "totalhours": 31,
                "_id": "64549a2d1666ee8236b1d833"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 2
    },
    {
        "_id": "64549f121666ee8236b1d897",
        "weekId": "18",
        "email": "Itachi@forg.onmicrosoft.com",
        "userId": "EMP1200",
        "userName": "Itachi Uchiha",
        "weekStartingDate": "08-05-2023",
        "weekEndingDate": "14-05-2023",
        "status": "Submitted",
        "reason": "",
        "reportingManager": "Suresh",
        "weekTotal": "54",
        "entrydata": [
            {
                "TotalHours": 0,
                "project": "MyIndia",
                "task": "logics",
                "day1": 24,
                "day2": 0,
                "day3": 0,
                "day4": 0,
                "day5": 0,
                "day6": 0,
                "day7": 0,
                "comments": "",
                "totalhours": 24,
                "_id": "64549f261666ee8236b1d89f"
            },
            {
                "TotalHours": 0,
                "project": "Force",
                "task": "Design",
                "day1": 0,
                "day2": 0,
                "day3": 3,
                "day4": 3,
                "day5": 0,
                "day6": 24,
                "day7": 0,
                "comments": "",
                "totalhours": 30,
                "_id": "64549f261666ee8236b1d8a0"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 1
    }
]
```

I need to show the data in separate columns to show Project-Name and Total hours in different row with individual columns.